# P = V²/R equation help

Tags: voltage, power

I’m currently learning about P=V<sup>2</sup>/R

I’ve been asked a question on how to use the dimensions of P and V to determine the dimension of R.
I know that
\$P=ML^2T^{-3}  \$
\$V=L^{0.5}M^{0.5}T^{-1}  ~\$ where L means Unit of Length, M is the unit of mass, and T=time.

Engineers in the EU and other Internationals use U or U(t) for volts and mostly America uses V or V(t) yet on the right \$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\$.

Why do they make this confusing? Is it inaccurate?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more context? Looks like something related to ohms law? Right now your question does not make much sense! Is it homework?

Comment: If you write V2R people will not know you mean V_squared. You must show that you mean exponentiation in some manner. || If you add 2 spaces at lne ends the markdown language starts a new line. If you leave no spaces the lines rap. I have added the spaces.

Comment: Both of your formulae  P=ML2T-3 and V=L0.5M0.5T-1 are unintelligible as written. The meaning of L, M, T are not understood. Why -3 and why -1. It probably makes sense but needs to be written in a manner that we can understand.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your formulas more clear. Note on EE we use `\$` instead of just `$` to start and end inline Mathjax.

Comment: If you mean to the power -1, write is as: T^(-1)

Comment: I’ve just added a photo to provide more context

Comment: @Calum: (1) 90% of that photo seems irrelevant. Can you crop it to the relevant parts. (2) You still haven't explained what M, L and T are despite being prompted. (3) You can write proper equations here using [MathJAX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). (4) How can you "*prove the value of R*"? If you mean **calculate** the value of R then please fix that too. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: I think the UK author should change their site from moodle  to muddle as in screw up units of length L and Capacitance as Q/V= [L?] too...  Disregard classical mechanical units...  Instead use the SI units of measure  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics)#References

Comment: Now I'll mess you up completely.  I learned it as \$P=\frac{E^2}{R}\$

Comment: Yes and do not confuse Units [V] with Symbols \$V\$ and  the table of capitalized classical mechanical equivalent units  especially L

Comment: Anyone else want to take a stab at this question?  @Transistor

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yes, I'd be fine dealing with it. No one else here seems to have a clue where these came from. (It was back in the day when they were wrestling with B and H fields.) But it is admittedly a confusing mess. Because there are at least four different systems that have evolved. We are lucky to have SI, today. Hasn't anyone here read a book on dimensional analysis and its history?

Comment: @CalumDavies Folks are not trying to make things confusing. But you have to keep in mind that there was a time when things like electrons and protons and even atoms weren't known. Yet they were playing with magnetic fields, which most certainly could produce "force," which they did understand well. So if you walked through the history of all this mess, you could see where they came up with those odd powers of a reduced set of dimensions (no SI amps, for example.)

Comment: @CalumDavies Ah. I found a paper that covers a lot of the necessary material to grasp. It's the [Babel of Units: The Evolution of Units Systems in Classical Electromagnetism](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1506/1506.01951.pdf). Saves me some work. Go look up the statCoulomb and abCoulomb in the paper. That should get you where you need to be. Keep in mind that a dyne is a unit of force they knew well. You can easily see from the paper where the units you see came about. I +1'd your question because of the fact that I think you brought up something that too many people have forgotten.

Comment: @CalumDavies A major major problem is that you are mixing up units with names. You are using V for Volt in one equation and V for velocity in the other. Tony's answer is probably confusing BUT contains what you need to "save" you. The SI symbol AND unit for Volt is V. The S/I units dimension for length is m/s = metres/second. It does not matter what the symbol for the NAME for velocity is BUT it is not V (that's Volt). So Power = Voltage_squared/Resistance. Velocity = Sqrt(Length x Mass)/Time. **You** then try to say Velocity = Volts.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It's kind of ironic that you bring up velocity. In the old electromagnetic units system (circa Maxwell still living and breathing), resistance has the same dimensions as velocity does. In the electrostatic units system (same time period) resistance has the same dimensions of velocity^(-1). The linked article I mentioned immediately above gives notice about this.

Answer (score 1):

The chart breaks the electrical units down into the base units.

An ohm is defined in terms of amperes and volts.  Amperes and volts are defined in terms of distances (in meters,) time (in seconds,) and mass (probably in grams.)

As I think the point of this exercise is to demonstrate the equivalence of electrical power and mechanical power, I'll just give you a hint:

Substitute the definitions for voltage, current, and power into the formula for electrical power (\$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\$).  You should be able to see how they all relate when you do that.

---

I've been reminded that the ampere is a base unit.  It can still, however, be described in terms of the simplest units (time, length, and mass.)  The chart the OP was given uses only those three to show the interrelationship of all the units.

Comment: then explain how C=[L]  yet  L=[L^-1T^2]

Comment: Is there any chance you would be able to talk me through this as this is my first time doing anything like this since I left college around 8 years ago so I can get to terms with how to do them again

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75:  capacitance = charge/voltage.   \$C = \frac{L^{1.5} \times M^{0.5} \times T^{-1} }{L^{0.5} \times M^{0.5} \times T^{-1} } = L\$

Comment: @CalumDavies:  I think not.  Its math you need to be able to do, and need to do yourself.  I don't know how your assignment wants to have it expressed.  The math is part of it, but part of it is also how you phrase the answer and frame the pieces so it makes sense.  I'm not good at that, even if I knew how your instructor expects it to be carried out.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: But, note that \$C=L\$ means that capacitance reduces to a length measurement rather than that C (capacitance) is equal to L (inductance.)

Comment: I see the ratio as an analogy yet it not valid for use in real engineering as pointed out

Comment: Also note that the chart says "**dimensions** of some common quantities encountered in engineering."  It's dimensional analysis here.

Comment: They'd better write: "dimensions of some **common quantities** encountered in engineering written in **highly unusual units**"

Comment: @Huisman:  The "highly unusual units" are metric base units.  All metric units reduce down to the base units at some point.  Which is kind of the point.  An electrical watt is in its base units obviously the same as a mechanical watt - which is (I assume) part of the lesson being taught in this assignment.

Comment: @JRE And therefore electical current reduces down to the **base** unit A, not to \$L^{1.5}M^{0.5}T^{-2}\$.

Comment: Watts of power may be compared but a four-dimensional space with  time  does not  describe electromagnetism.  Nor a 5 dimensional one with mass. These dimensions are "abstract" for  Electromagnetism

Comment: @Huisman:  Amperes are not a base unit.  Amperes are a derived unit. Another point to the lesson.

Comment: @JRE ampere is a [base unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit) (even before May 2019 as I referred to in a deleted comment)

Comment: @Huisman:  I missed them redefining things behind my back.

Comment: @JRE Even before May 2019 ampere was a base unit. In May 2019, they only redefined the base units using constants. So, I stand my case that it is weird to express current other than in amperes.

Comment: The ampere can still be described in dimensions of the other units.  The chart that kicked off this whole thing does just that.  The fact that you can describe amperes in terms of other units is what allowed the redefinition to work.  Define the ampere, then work backwards from that to get the kilogram.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard MOODLE Site for this using classical mechanical units...on Electrical units of measure  (in yellow)
[image]

Instead use the SI units of measure  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics)#References

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Derived_units

Keep in mind you will see history changes as Voltage symbol has migrated from E to U and E to V  and don't confuse the units W with the symbol for power , P

Below are UNITS ONLY Watts,W Volts V and Amps, A and not Symbols like P,V,I or P, U, I or P, E,I as done in the old days.

[image]

[image]

Read the Wiki history for clarity.

Comment: Just to clarify, Moodle is a "learning management system" used by schools to provide content to their students. Any technical content on a moodle page was almost certainly put there by some course instructor. It looks like the OP is taking an online course or possibly an online exam.

Comment: Yet teaching unusable units for dimensions in electricity

Comment: As @JRE says, the question is about dimensional analysis - this answer is confusing and unhelpful

Comment: How is the dimension of Length useful to Capacitance?  @NMF  I merely challenged the assumptions that these are common dimensions in Engineering .  They are not.  Yet the dimensions I showed are used and are useful

Comment: except may not   useful for capacitance = \$ kg^{−1}⋅m^{−2}⋅s^4⋅A^2\$  but at least it is more accurate than capacitance in meters (L)

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 I think you're missing the point of dimensional analysis - it is well-covered in many places online, might be worth a read. I don't disagree with the usefulness of the units mentioned in your answer - they just don't answer the OP's question

Comment: @NMF I believe the question is outdated without Amps in dimensions

Comment: @NMF I consider that Tony's answer provided a useful amount of insigh and direction to the OP - should he care to take time to extract that which ha can understand. A very majr problem with the OP's question is that he has used V for Volt and V for velocity without discernment. Tony's suggestion to use SI units would by itself demonsrate the original error.

Comment: I just saw another error in the Ohm's law chart where they use units of W,V,A, but instead of \$\Omega\$ they use symbol R which goes with {P,V,I}

Comment: @Russell McMahon - I respectfully disagree, and your 'answer' isn't an answer. All the OP needs to do is a bit of simple mathematical manipulation - which understandably he appears to be a bit rusty in.

Comment: @NMF Sadly, I have to agree that you are correct :-( :-). My answer is wrong. Brain fade somewhere. I'll try to get back to repl;ace it completely but, for now have added an "Unclean! Unclean" notice. Bell sounds off. Or equivalent.